# Numpy getting the max of certain cells based on a neighboring cell

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing

I am very new to any kind of programming and python is the first language I started learning, about a few months a go, so any help would be really appreciated!

I have the following numpy array:

```
    0    1

0   38  40
1   39  46
2   38  43
3   40  51
4   41  44
```

What I want to do is to, first, find the max value from the last column --here it's [3][1]-- and then move on to the previous column and also get the max value, but only among the cells that have the following values: 38, 38, and 39.

In other words, I don't want cells [3][0] and [4][0] to be included in the search for the max value at the next column.

It would also be great if I can extract the indices of each cell with the maximum value as well.

Edit: I honestly don't know where to start! And I tried multiple things, and one of them is the following:

```
arr = np.array([[38,40], [39,46], [38,43], [40,51], [41,44]])
for index, cell in np.ndenumerate(arr):
    for i in arr[:,-1]:
        if i == np.max(arr[:,-1]):
            print(i)
            for j in arr[:,-2]:
                if j == np.max(arr[0:2,-2]):
                    print(j)
    break
```

This works, and it gives the following output:

```
51
39
```

But I would like to do this on a much bigger matrix, where I would not necessarily know the indices of the cells that have the max value.

Comment: what have you tryied?

Comment: I edited my question above. If you can take a look at it, that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

You could take leverange from `np.max`, `np.argmax` and indexing un numpy arrays. Here the solution, then an explanation of every method and indexing

```
import numpy as np


arr = np.array([[38,40], [39,46], [38,43], [40,51], [41,44]])


col1_maxVal = np.max(arr[:,1])
col1_maxIdx = np.argmax(arr[:,1])

col0_maxVal_restricted = np.max(arr[:col1_maxIdx,0])
col0_maxIdx_restricted = np.max(arr[:col1_maxIdx,0])

print(col1_maxVal,col0_maxVal_restricted)
```

### np.max

Return the maximun value of an array (check https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.max.html?highlight=max#numpy.ndarray.max  for detailed explanation)

### np.argmax

Returns the index where the array has maximun value (check https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html for detailed explanation )

### Indexing

you could get a "chunk" of an array just as `startIdx:endIdx` and if start is 0 or end is 0 you could not write it. so in this case when you do

`arr[:col1_maxIdx]` you're croping and returning the first 3 rows of the array